# Changing text inside a div element that is not part of any tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a div element like this:

```
<div class="span5">
    <div id="msg" class="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Hello!</strong> world
    </div>
</div>
```

And wish to just change the text inside the `msg` element. How can I change the text that is not part of any tag (in this case `world`)

I'm doing this for now to change the text in `<strong>`:

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
  $("#msg strong").html("Bye");
});
```

I don't want to wrap `world` in any tags unless they don't mess with any formatting.

Comment: this reminds me of a puppy chasing its tail! use a span with a distinct class name.

Comment: You should not use text "that is not part of any tag" in HTML. Always follow well-formatted rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` tags, unless you mess them up in CSS, by definition do not apply any formatting. I use them for exactly this purpose quite often.

```
<div class="span5">
    <div id="msg" class="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Hello!</strong> <span id="world">world</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that and I don't think you should do that, I think it's better to select specific elements of your DOM better than 'anything that doesn't have any tag', that can easily be different in the future.
Why don't you wrap it with a span or something like this?

From [w3schools span](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp):

> The <span> tag provides no visual change by itself

Answer (score 0):

span is one solution. as an alternative, you can also iterate over childNodes and change the last text node. (ofcourse I would also recommend the span approach).

```
var allNodes = $("#msg")[0].childNodes;
var textNode = allNodes[allNodes.length-1];
textNode.nodeValue = "bye";
```